# Разложить в php ответ из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Доброе утро, уважаемые!
Получаю вывод из MySQL таблицы в таком виде:

```
id_man..........kolichestvo        
01..................12
01..................2
01..................5
01..................6
02..................3
03..................9
03..................4
04..................14
05..................9
05..................7
```

В итоге нужно получить сгруппированные данные в таком виде (на примере **01**):

```
id_man......kol-vo_total.....strok
01...............23...........4
```

где **23** - общая сумма по столбцу **kolichestvo**, **4** - сколько раз встречается **01** в выдаче результата (**строк**).

Понимаю, что нужно загнать выдачу в массив, просчитать, и выдать. Просьба: направьте, куда нужно копать?

Comment: Надо в самом mysql обернуть это еще в один запрос (что бы текущий запрос оказался в FROM нового) и выглядеть он будет как `select id_man, sum(kol_vo), count(1) strok from (....запрос...) x group by id_man`

Comment: *Получаю вывод из MySQL таблицы в таком виде* Или см. выше, или откорректируйте исходный запрос (вероятно, потребуется изменить выражение группировки) так, чтобы он сразу давал требуемые данные.

Comment: Дело в том, что поле kolichestvo получаю методом  COUNT(*) и просуммировать его проблематично

Comment: это никак не противоречит данному вам ответу.  завернуть первый запрос в еще один, select id_man, sum(kol_vo), count(1) strok from (...ваш первый запрос...)

Comment: Делаю запрос: 

select id_man, sum(kol_vo), count(1) strok from (SELECT id_man, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE zapros_date = '03.04.2019') GROUP BY id_man)

на что MySql ругается: `Every derived table must have its own alias`. Где  и что я здесь опустил из виду?

Comment: Не публикуйте существенные сведения (особенно код) в комментарии. Корректируйте текст вопроса (ссылка "править" под ним), возможно, с пометкой UPDATE.

Comment: *MySql ругается: `Every derived table must have its own alias`* Добавьте любой алиас после скобки, закрывающей подзапрос, перед финальным GROUP BY. Да и `COUNT(*)` как-то остался без алиаса...

Comment: А вообще лучше просто приведите DDL таблицы, образец данных и желаемый при таких данных результат. Ибо, судя по запросу в комментарии,  у Вас сплошь "масло масляное"...

Comment: _Добавьте любой алиас после скобки, закрывающей подзапрос, перед финальным GROUP BY. Да и COUNT(*) как-то остался без алиаса_
Сделал, но в итоге получил общее количество по столбцам **kolichestvo** и **strok**. Т.е. все "склеилось" в одну строку

Comment: DDL таблицы - это, как ее схема?



`id (primary) ...... id_man ..... kolichestvo ..... zapros_date ..... zapros`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91976/discussion-between---and-akina).